# Idiomatic construction to check whether a collection is ordered

Tags: scala, recursion, fold, idioms

With the intention of learning and further to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822467/tail-recursion-issue/7823320#7823320), I've remained curious of the idiomatic alternatives to explicit recursion for an algorithm that checks whether a list (or collection) is ordered.  (I'm keeping things simple here by using an operator to compare and Int as type; I'd like to look at the algorithm before delving into the generics of it)

The basic recursive version would be (by @Luigi Plinge):

```
def isOrdered(l:List[Int]): Boolean = l match {
  case Nil => true
  case x :: Nil => true
  case x :: xs => x <= xs.head && isOrdered(xs)
}
```

A poor performing idiomatic way would be:

```
def isOrdered(l: List[Int]) = l == l.sorted
```

An alternative algorithm using fold:

```
def isOrdered(l: List[Int]) =
  l.foldLeft((true, None:Option[Int]))((x,y) =>
    (x._1 && x._2.map(_ <= y).getOrElse(true), Some(y)))._1
```

It has the drawback that it will compare for all n elements of the list even if it could stop earlier after finding the first out-of-order element. Is there a way to "stop" fold and therefore making this a better solution?

Any other (elegant) alternatives?

Comment: Using Booleans as values from `if` statements makes me sad, and Luigi's version was slightly off (detecting reverse order). Fixed it for you.

Comment: @Apocalisp your "corrected" version returns true on `isOrdered(List(1,2,1,2))`, which is why I rolled it back, and is why I'm changing it back again...

Comment: It should be noted that `l == l.sorted` might not work for lists of objects other than ints if the sorting algorithm used isn't stable.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By "idiomatic", I assume you're talking about McBride and Paterson's "Idioms" in their paper [Applicative Programming With Effects](http://strictlypositive.org/Idiom.pdf). :o)

Here's how you would use their idioms to check if a collection is ordered:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

case class Lte[A](v: A, b: Boolean)

implicit def lteSemigroup[A:Order] = new Semigroup[Lte[A]] {
  def append(a1: Lte[A], a2: => Lte[A]) = {
    lazy val b = a1.v lte a2.v
    Lte(if (!a1.b || b) a1.v else a2.v, a1.b && b && a2.b)
  }
}

def isOrdered[T[_]:Traverse, A:Order](ta: T[A]) =
  ta.foldMapDefault(x => some(Lte(x, true))).fold(_.b, true)
```

Here's how this works:

Any data structure `T[A]` where there exists an implementation of `Traverse[T]`, can be traversed with an `Applicative` functor, or "idiom", or "strong lax monoidal functor". It just so happens that every `Monoid` induces such an idiom for free (see section 4 of the paper).

A monoid is just an associative binary operation over some type, and an identity element for that operation. I'm defining a `Semigroup[Lte[A]]` (a semigroup is the same as a monoid, except without the identity element) whose associative operation tracks the lesser of two values and whether the left value is less than the right value. And of course `Option[Lte[A]]` is just the monoid generated freely by our semigroup.

Finally, `foldMapDefault` traverses the collection type `T` in the idiom induced by the monoid. The result `b` will contain true if each value was less than all the following ones (meaning the collection was ordered), or `None` if the `T` had no elements. Since an empty `T` is sorted by convention, we pass `true` as the second argument to the final `fold` of the `Option`.

As a bonus, this works for all traversable collections. A demo:

```
scala> val b = isOrdered(List(1,3,5,7,123))
b: Boolean = true

scala> val b = isOrdered(Seq(5,7,2,3,6))
b: Boolean = false

scala> val b = isOrdered(Map((2 -> 22, 33 -> 3)))
b: Boolean = true

scala> val b = isOrdered(some("hello"))
b: Boolean = true
```

A test:

```
import org.scalacheck._

scala> val p = forAll((xs: List[Int]) => (xs /== xs.sorted) ==> !isOrdered(xs))
p:org.scalacheck.Prop = Prop

scala> val q = forAll((xs: List[Int]) => isOrdered(xs.sorted))
q: org.scalacheck.Prop = Prop

scala> p && q check
+ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

And *that's* how you do **idiomatic** traversal to detect if a collection is ordered.

Comment: Any sufficiently abstract code is indistinguishable from magic.

Comment: Whether or not the whole structure is traversed depends on the strictness of the implementation of `Traverse` and `Applicative`.

Comment: +1 for the paper and applying its knowledge to answer this question

Comment: @Apocalisp & everyone - I would welcome your comments, positive or negative, on [this Meta question on "advanced" SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134333/how-to-avoid-scaring-off-beginners-with-advanced-answers), which uses this answer as an example. Please note that I do recognise that this answer is useful, and I did upvote it, so I hope no-one is offended.

Comment: @RobinGreen Sure, no problem. I have downvoted your question. :)

Answer (score 63):

This will exit after the first element that is out of order. It should thus perform well, but I haven't tested that. It's also a lot more elegant in my opinion. :)

```
def sorted(l:List[Int]) = l.view.zip(l.tail).forall(x => x._1 <= x._2)
```

Comment: @missingfaktor: won't that always go through the whole list?

Comment: No, it won't. See the implementation of `forall` [here](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/Tuple2.scala#L119).

Comment: this will fail on an empty list with `Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list`, but the fix is pretty simple: `def sorted(l:List[Int]) = l.isEmpty || l.view.zip(l.tail).forall(x => x._1 <= x._2)`

Comment: This comment is added a couple of years later using Scala 10.2 .  For efficiency, we should use a stream:`l.view.zip(l.tail).toStream.forall(x => x._1 <= x._2)`.  Then the zip operation won't be carried out on the full list if it fails early.

Comment: Here is a broader signature of this method: `def isSorted[T <% Ordered[T]](l: Iterable[T])`

Answer (score 8):

I'm going with this, which is pretty similar to Kim Stebel's, as a matter of fact.

```
def isOrdered(list: List[Int]): Boolean = (
  list 
  sliding 2 
  map { 
    case List(a, b) => () => a < b 
  } 
  forall (_())
)
```

Comment: `list.sliding(2).map({ case List(a, b) => a < b }).forall(identity)` would be slightly more efficient.

Comment: @missingfaktor Ah, yes, `sliding` returns an `Iterator`! Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 6):

In case you missed missingfaktor's elegant solution in the comments [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852918/446554):

## Scala < 2.13.0

```
(l, l.tail).zipped.forall(_ <= _)
```

## Scala 2.13.x+

```
l.lazyZip(l.tail).forall(_ <= _)
```

This solution is very readable and will exit on the first out-of-order element.

Comment: apparently `.zipped` is deprecated, so `l.lazyZip(l.tail).forall(_ <= _)`

Answer (score 2):

The recursive version is fine, but limited to `List` (with limited changes, it would work well on `LinearSeq`).

If it was implemented in the standard library (would make sense) it would probably be done in `IterableLike` and have a completely imperative implementation (see for instance method `find`)

You can interrupt the `foldLeft` with a `return` (in which case you need only the previous element and not boolean all along)

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
def isOrdered[A: Ordering](seq: Seq[A]): Boolean = {
  if (!seq.isEmpty)
    seq.tail.foldLeft(seq.head){(previous, current) => 
      if (previous > current) return false; current
    }
  true
}
```

but I don't see how it is any better or even idiomatic than an imperative implementation. I'm not sure I would not call it imperative actually.

Another solution could be

```
def isOrdered[A: Ordering](seq: Seq[A]): Boolean = 
  ! seq.sliding(2).exists{s => s.length == 2 && s(0) > s(1)}
```

Rather concise, and maybe that could be called idiomatic, I'm not sure. But I think it is not too clear. Moreover, all of those methods would probably perform much worse than the imperative or tail recursive version, and I do not think they have any added clarity that would buy that.

Also you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7830471/754787).

Answer (score 1):

To stop iteration, you can use [Iteratee](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/):

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import IterV._
import math.Ordering
import Ordering.Implicits._

implicit val ListEnumerator = new Enumerator[List] {
  def apply[E, A](e: List[E], i: IterV[E, A]): IterV[E, A] = e match {
    case List() => i
    case x :: xs => i.fold(done = (_, _) => i,
                           cont = k => apply(xs, k(El(x))))
  }
}

def sorted[E: Ordering] : IterV[E, Boolean] = {
  def step(is: Boolean, e: E)(s: Input[E]): IterV[E, Boolean] = 
    s(el = e2 => if (is && e < e2)
                   Cont(step(is, e2))
                 else
                   Done(false, EOF[E]),
      empty = Cont(step(is, e)),
      eof = Done(is, EOF[E]))

  def first(s: Input[E]): IterV[E, Boolean] = 
    s(el = e1 => Cont(step(true, e1)),
      empty = Cont(first),
      eof = Done(true, EOF[E]))

  Cont(first)
}


scala> val s = sorted[Int]
s: scalaz.IterV[Int,Boolean] = scalaz.IterV$Cont$$anon$2@5e9132b3

scala> s(List(1,2,3)).run
res11: Boolean = true

scala> s(List(1,2,3,0)).run
res12: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split the List into two parts, and check whether the last of the first part is lower than the first of the second part. If so, you could check in **parallel** for both parts. Here the schematic idea, first without parallel:

```
def isOrdered (l: List [Int]): Boolean = l.size/2 match {
  case 0 => true 
  case m => {
    val  low = l.take (m)
    val high = l.drop (m)
    low.last <= high.head && isOrdered (low) && isOrdered (high) 
  }
}
```

And now with parallel, and using `splitAt` instead of `take/drop`:

```
def isOrdered (l: List[Int]): Boolean = l.size/2 match {
  case 0 => true 
  case m => {
    val (low, high) = l.splitAt (m)
    low.last <= high.head && ! List (low, high).par.exists (x => isOrdered (x) == false) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isSorted[A <: Ordered[A]](sequence: List[A]): Boolean = {
  sequence match {
    case Nil        => true
    case x::Nil     => true
    case x::y::rest => (x < y) && isSorted(y::rest)
  }
}

Explain how it works.
```

Comment: Won't compile on anything beyond an empty `List`.

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just posting code, so that others can learn from it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

my solution combine with missingfaktor's solution and Ordering

```
def isSorted[T](l: Seq[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = (l, l.tail).zipped.forall(ord.lt(_, _))
```

and you can use your own comparison method. E.g.

```
isSorted(dataList)(Ordering.by[Post, Date](_.lastUpdateTime))
```