# Scalaz iteratee, create Enumerator for BufferedReader

Tags: scala, scalaz

How is it possible to create Enumerator for BufferedReader?

I found rather old article: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/scalaz-tutorial-enumeration-based-io-with-iteratees/ and it looks like it doesn't work with Scalaz 6.0.4

I try to create Enumerator based on example from here: [Idiomatic construction to check whether a collection is ordered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852471/idiomatic-construction-to-check-whether-a-collection-is-ordered)

```
 implicit val ListEnumerator = new Enumerator[List] {
   def apply[E, A](e: List[E], i: IterV[E, A]): IterV[E, A] = e match {
      case List() => i
      case x :: xs => i.fold(done = (_, _) => i,
                       cont = k => apply(xs, k(El(x))))
   }
 }
```

But I can't understand how to combine IO monad with Enumerator

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with Rúnar's article? The following version is working for me (Scalaz 6.0.4):

```
object FileIteratee {
  def enumReader[A](r: BufferedReader, it: IterV[String,  A]) : IO[IterV[String,  A]] = {
    def loop: IterV[String,  A] => IO[IterV[String,  A]] = {
      case i@Done(_, _) => i.pure[IO]
      case i@Cont(k) => for {
        s <- r.readLine.pure[IO]
        a <- if (s == null) i.pure[IO] else loop(k(El(s)))
      } yield a
    }
    loop(it)
  }

  def bufferFile(f: File) = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)).pure[IO]

  def closeReader(r: Reader) = r.close().pure[IO]

  def bracket[A,B,C](init: IO[A], fin: A => IO[B], body: A => IO[C]): IO[C] =
    for {
      a <- init
      c <- body(a)
      _ <- fin(a)
    } yield c

  def enumFile[A](f: File,  i: IterV[String,  A]) : IO[IterV[String, A]] =
    bracket(bufferFile(f),
            closeReader(_: BufferedReader),
            enumReader(_: BufferedReader,  i))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But as I understand scalaz evolution, from 6 version more convenient way is to provide Enumerator